# Class was taken place?

Tags: past-tense

When a class taken by a teacher, what the best  way to speak that?

"the class was taken place"

I think the above sentence is not too good for speaking.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand either "the class was taken place" or "when a class taken by a teacher".  I know that "The class took place." is a grammatically sound and sensible sentence, but I do not know that it means what you intend to mean.

Comment: OP's "Class taken by a teacher" may use an old-fashioned idiom in which "take" is used in the sense "undertake, perform". I have the impression that this use is still frequent in Indian English.

Comment: Ah, so OP might have been looking for something closer to "the class was given", "the class was taught" or "the class was conducted" -- some passive voice construction that grammatically implies an agent like a teacher.  That would be quite different than the intransitive sense of "the class took place" or "the class had taken place".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *To take* when the object is a "class" means "to enroll and attend a class."  It won't mean going to a classroom for a single day, but refers to the entire long process of completing a course, which is sometimes also called a class.
- *To take place* is a phrasal verb meaning "to happen."

So both those expressions mean different things.

So, it depends on what you want to say (I can't figure it out from your example):

- If you want to say that in the past you completed all classes of a course on X, you can say *I took a class on X* or *I have taken a class on X*.
- If you want to say that a single class of a course has happened, you can say *The class took place* or *The class has taken place.*